# Retrieve Element of XDocument by name

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document. I want to retrieve a specific descendant node of the root node. The root node does not have a namespace, however, the children nodes do, although they are all the same. What is the best way to retrieve this element as an element?

Comment: How about using XPath to navigate the XML hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace of the root node doesn't matter.

You can just write

```
XNamespace ns = "http://...";
var elem = doc.Element(ns + "TagName");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the namespace of the children you could match them by [`LocalName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.localname.aspx), which refers to the local (unqualified) part of the name.

```
string name = "purchase";
var query = xml.Descendants()
               .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == name);
```

This returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>`. From there you can loop over it or use [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) if you expect only one to exist.